# how to get the critical region for a uniformly most powerful test for mean of normal?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, normal-distribution, neyman-pearson-lemma

I need help in understanding how to construct a uniformly most powerful test using the Neyman-Pearson lemma. Here is an excerpt in my text that I have trouble following:

[image]

I have no idea how to get $(5.4)$. The fact that my text skips the steps seems to imply that this is something straightforward but I am still stumped. I also don't see the point of observing that the relationship between the likelihood ratio and $\bar{Y}$ when $\mu_0<\mu_1$ and $\mu_0>\mu_1$.

**What I've tried**

By the Newyman-Pearson lemma, I know that the critical region will satisfy :

$$ L_\mathbf{Y}(\mu_1;\mathbf{Y}) - k_\alpha L_\mathbf{Y}(\mu_0;\mathbf{Y}))>0$$

where $k_\alpha$ is some constant that depends on the size of the test, $\alpha$,

This means:

$$ \frac{L_\mathbf{Y}(\mu_1;\mathbf{Y})}{L_\mathbf{Y}(\mu_0;\mathbf{Y}))} > k_\alpha $$

So, using the given likelihood ratio, I have:

$$\exp\left\{\frac{n}{2\sigma^2}\left[(\mu_0-\mu_1)(\mu_0+\mu_1-2\bar{Y})\right]\right\} >k_\alpha$$

So, solving for $\bar{Y}$, I get:

$$ \bar{Y} \lt -\frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{\ln(k_\alpha)2\sigma^2-n(\mu_0^2-\mu_1^2)}{n(\mu_0-\mu_1)}\right]$$

I don't know how to proceed at this point. Also, so far I don't see how anything would change is assumed $\mu_0>\mu_1$ instead.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag (you seem to already follow the guidelines at its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), but it wouldn't hurt to take a look at them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me use a slightly different but equivalent formulation in which the likelihood under the null is in the numerator, and hence we reject for *small* likelihood ratios.

Consider testing the version of the problem as stated in your screenshot, $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$ vs. $H_1:\mu=\mu_1$, where $\mu_1>\mu_0$ for a r.s. of size $n$ from a $N(\mu,1)$ population (if $\sigma^2$ is known, we may as well set it to 1 for simplicity).

We first show that, for a Neyman-Pearson cutoff value $k_\alpha$ for the likelihood ratio, the rejection region of the Neyman-Pearson test can be written in terms of $\bar{y}$ as
    $$
    \bar{y}>\frac{\ln k_\alpha-\frac{n}{2}(\mu_1^2-\mu_0^2)}{n(\mu_0-\mu_1)}\equiv K
    $$
The likelihood is
     $$
L(\mu;y)=\prod_i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y_i-\mu)^2}{2}}=(2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{\sum_i(y_i-\mu)^2}{2}}
     $$
     Thus,
     \begin{align*}
    \lambda(y)&=\frac{L(\mu_0;y)}{L(\mu_1;y)}\\
    &=\frac{(2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{\sum_i(y_i-\mu_0)^2}{2}}}{(2\pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{\sum_i(y_i-\mu_1)^2}{2}}}\\
              &=e^{\frac{1}{2}[\sum_i(y_i^2-2\mu_1 y_i+\mu_1^2)-\sum_i(y_i^2-2\mu_0 y_i+\mu_0^2)]}\\
              &=e^{(\mu_0-\mu_1)\sum_i y_i+\frac{1}{2}(n\mu_1^2-n\mu_0^2)}\\
              &=e^{(\mu_0-\mu_1)n\bar{y}+\frac{n}{2}(\mu_1^2-\mu_0^2)}<k_\alpha\\
      \end{align*}
Then $$n(\mu_0-\mu_1)\bar{y}+\frac{n}{2}(\mu_1^2-\mu_0^2)<\ln k_\alpha\Rightarrow n(\mu_0-\mu_1)\bar{y}<\ln k_\alpha-\frac{n}{2}(\mu_1^2-\mu_0^2).$$ Hence
$$
\bar{y}\overset{\mu_0<\mu_1}{>}\frac{\ln k_\alpha-\frac{n}{2}(\mu_1^2-\mu_0^2)}{n(\mu_0-\mu_1)}\equiv K,
$$
so I simply *call* the rhs of the inequality $K$ (which implicitly depends on $\alpha$ and $n$).

Here, you also see that whether the value under the alternative is higher or lower matters in that we divide the inequality by either a positive or a negative difference, so that the inequality sign reverses or not.

We next show that the critical value $K$ is such that $$K=\mu_0+\frac{z_{(1-\alpha)}}{\sqrt{n}},$$ where $z_{(1-\alpha)}$ is the $1-\alpha$ quantile of the standard normal distribution. The key thing to note here is that the critical region has to have size $\alpha$ (just another way of saying we want a level-$\alpha$ test, so reject a true null in 5% of the cases, so want a probability that our test statistic $\bar{y}$ is larger than the $K$ of 5% under the null).

Under the null, we have
$$\bar{y}\sim N\left(\mu_0,\frac{1}{n}\right)\Rightarrow \frac{\bar{y}-\mu_0}{\sqrt{1/n}}\sim N(0,1)$$
 Hence, $K$ needs to be such that, when the null is true,
     \begin{align*}
     &P(\bar{y}>K)=\alpha\\
\Rightarrow & P\left(\frac{\bar{y}-\mu_0}{\sqrt{1/n}}>\frac{K-\mu_0}{\sqrt{1/n}}\right)=\alpha\\
\Rightarrow & \frac{K-\mu_0}{\sqrt{1/n}}=z_{(1-\alpha)}\\
\Rightarrow &K=\mu_0+\frac{z_{(1-\alpha)}}{\sqrt{n}}
     \end{align*}
Here, the 2nd-to-last line follows because $z_{(1-\alpha)}$ is, by definition, the value that is exceeded with probability $\alpha$ for a $N(0,1)$-r.v.